Cycle Through Table Filter Criteria Using One Button with Multiple Clicks
I have a table with multiple columns. One column (Business Unit) has four possible criteria (KB-L, KB-P, KB-C, and KB-T).
I'd like a button in Excel to click and loop through the filter for each value in the Business Unit column.
Example:

1st click shows only rows with KB-L values in the Business Unit column.
2nd click shows only rows with KB-P values in the Business Unit column.
3rd click shows only rows with KB-C values in the Business Unit column.
4th click shows only rows with KB-T values in the Business Unit column.
5th click removes the filter and shows all rows, including rows with blanks in the Business Unit column.

After the 5th click, the loop should repeat upon the next click starting with showing only KB-L values.
I know how to hide rows based on criteria in a specific column.
Sub Cycle_Business_Unit()

For Each cell In Range("I11:I99999")
    If cell.Value = "KB-L" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell

End Sub

How do I loop it so that upon each button click it cycles through the five possibilities?


Assuming there is an Excel table (create by Ctrl+T) on worksheet.
It’s easy to expand or change the order of criteria by simply updating CRITS. Note: The first and last items must be the same.

Option Explicit
Sub ClickEvent()
    Const CRITS = "KB-L KB-P KB-C KB-T KB-- KB-L"
    Const TARGET_COL = "Business Unit"
    Dim aCrit, i, oTab As ListObject, iCol As Long
    Dim sCrit As String
    aCrit = Split(CRITS)
    Set oTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    iCol = oTab.ListColumns(TARGET_COL).Index
    If oTab.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        ' activate autofiler
        oTab.Range.AutoFilter
    End If
    If oTab.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
        ' if there is a filter on target col
        If oTab.AutoFilter.Filters(iCol).On Then
            ' get the current critera
            sCrit = Mid(oTab.AutoFilter.Filters(iCol).Criteria1, 2)
            ' get the next critera
            sCrit = aCrit((InStr(1, CRITS, sCrit) \ 5) + 1)
        Else
            sCrit = "KB-L"
        End If
    Else
        sCrit = "KB-L"
    End If
    ' update autofilter
    If sCrit = "KB--" Then ' show all
        oTab.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
    Else
        oTab.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=" & sCrit
    End If
End Sub



Dear Taller,
This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for all of your help!

What should I do when someone answers my question?

Expanded your code with the Case method
Dim click_count as Long

Sub Cycle_Business_Unit()

click_count = click_count + 1
If click_count = 6 Then click_count = 1
Range("I11:I99999").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  Select Case click_count
    Case 1
    For Each cell In Range("I11:I99999")
      If cell.Value = "KB-L" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell
    Case 2
    For Each cell In Range("I11:I99999")
      If cell.Value = "KB-P" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell
    Case 3
    For Each cell In Range("I11:I99999")
      If cell.Value = "KB-C" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell
    Case 4
    For Each cell In Range("I11:I99999")
      If cell.Value = "KB-T" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell
    Case 5
      'show all or something else
  End Select
End Sub

If specify only the used range for the For Each, this shortens runtime.

Hello Black Cat,
Thanks for your input. It looks like I may have confused you with the code I added. The code you provided hides the row containing the specified criteria. I need the code to show only the specified criteria. I changed the "=" sign to a "<>" operator but it freezes excel when the code is executed.
Example, if KB-L is present then KB-C, KB-P, and KB-T are hidden.

Sure. In this case the other mod is to change the Hidden property assignment.
